# Dealing with abstract classes in Jackson deserialization in Java

Tags: java, jackson

I have implemented a wrapper over `OkHttpClient`. Which has two classes `Get` and `Post` that can be executed to get response of type specified with the instance of `Get` and `Post`. It looks like below,

`HttpMethod` is the base class looks like

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type",
        visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = Get.class,
        name = HttpMethodType.GET_NAME
),@JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = Post.class,
        name = HttpMethodType.POST_NAME
)})
public abstract class HttpMethod<R> {

    protected static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS = 60000; // 60 seconds

    private HttpMethodType type;

    protected HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration;

    // Start path with a `/`, also include query string
    protected String path;

    protected Map<String, String> headers;

    private TypeReference<R> outputType;

    protected HttpMethod(HttpMethodType type,
                         @Valid HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration,
                         Map<String, String> headers,
                         TypeReference<R> outputType,
                         String path) {

        this.type = type;
        this.httpConfiguration = httpConfiguration;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.outputType = outputType;
        this.path = path;
    }

    /**
     * Object will be parsed object of type R if type is not null, else it will be string
     */
    public R execute() throws IOException {
        Response response = executeCall();
        return parse(response);
    }

    protected abstract Response executeCall() throws IOException;

    protected GenericErrorResponse parseUnsuccessfulResponse(Response response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                String json = responseBody.string();
                return MapperUtils.deserialize(json, GenericErrorResponse.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw TarkshalaServiceException.create(SerializationErrorCode.getInstance());
            }
        }

        throw TarkshalaServiceException.create(SerializationErrorCode.getInstance());
    }

    protected R parse(Response response) {

        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            GenericErrorResponse errorResponse = parseUnsuccessfulResponse(response);
            throw TarkshalaServiceException.create(NonSuccessResponseErrorCode.getInstance(response.code(), errorResponse.getErrorCode()));
        }

        try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
            String json = responseBody.string();
            if (outputType != null) {
                return MapperUtils.deserialize(json, outputType);
            }

            throw TarkshalaServiceException.create(SerializationErrorCode.getInstance());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw TarkshalaServiceException.create(SerializationErrorCode.getInstance());
        }
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return String.format("%s%s", httpConfiguration.url(), path);
    }
}
```

`Get` and `Post` implement it as following

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Get<R> extends HttpMethod<R> {

    @Builder
    public Get(@Valid HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration,
               Map<String, String> headers,
               TypeReference<R> outputType,
               String path) {
        super(HttpMethodType.GET, httpConfiguration, headers, outputType, path);
    }

    protected Response executeCall() throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .callTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
        requestBuilder.url(getUrl());

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            requestBuilder.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        Request request = requestBuilder.get().build();

        return client.newCall(request).execute();
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post<R> extends HttpMethod<R> {

    private Object requestBody;

    @Builder
    public Post(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration,
                   Map<String, String> headers,
                   TypeReference<R> outputType,
                   String path,
                   Object requestBody) {
        super(HttpMethodType.POST, httpConfiguration, headers, outputType, path);
        this.requestBody = requestBody;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response executeCall() throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .callTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
        requestBuilder.url(getUrl());

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            requestBuilder.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), MapperUtils.serializeAsJson(this.requestBody));

        Request request = requestBuilder.post(body).build();

        return client.newCall(request).execute();
    }
}
```

I want to serialize and deserialize these, in order to store these to db and send over wire. But I am getting following error while deserializing

```
ERROR [2023-05-28 02:13:21,576] io.dropwizard.jersey.jackson.JsonProcessingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 3cddc3a0922e1cbe
! com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
!  at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 11, column: 19] (through reference chain: com.tarkshala.tavahot.ms.clockwork.models.ScheduleJobRequest["httpRequest"]->com.tarkshala.common.http.Get["outputType"])
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1904)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1349)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:274)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
```

I understand that this is happening because Jackson need Concrete class to deserialize. Is there a way around to achieve this?

Comment: See the linked duplicate, and in particular [this link to the Jackson docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) from there.